# How to set two regimes for Sys.sleep in a loop

Tags: r

I would like to have 2 sets of Sys.sleep. One long one and very short at each iteration. The current example does the first "long sleep" however doesn't proceed with the next one.

Here is example:

```
out <- as.numeric()

for(i in 1:20){
 out[i] <- i*5
  if(i==seq(5,20,5)){
   Sys.sleep(5); print("Long sleep")
  } else {
    for(j in 1:5){
     Sys.sleep(0.15); cat(j)
 }}}

out
```

The loop should have a "Long sleep" with 5sec at each 5th iteration and 0.15sec at each iteration.

What I'm doing wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: Use `if (i%in%seq(5,20,5))`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error `the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used` should have been an indicator that your `if` test was incorrect. Let's try it on the console:

```
i <- 5
i == seq(5,20,5)
## [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

When you do that in an `if` statement, it is expecting one and only one logical out of the comparison, so it is rightfully confused. (Which would you use?)

Perhaps you meant `i %in% seq(5,20,5)`? Even better, I suggest you pre-assign the sequence and compare against it, otherwise you are creating a static vector every time.

```
myseq <- seq(5,20,5)
for(i in 1:20) {
    out[i] <- i*5
    if(i %in% myseq) {
        Sys.sleep(5); print("Long sleep")
    } else {
        for(j in 1:5) {
            Sys.sleep(0.15); cat(j)
        }
    }
}
```

As an alternative, you could also check `(i %% 5 == 0)`, which can be faster, depending on the size of your test sequence.